# MPEG-DASH cannot decrypt mp4 with clearkey

Tags: mpeg-dash, dash.js, mp4box

i have an audio-only mp4 file encrypted with MP4Box, with command `MP4BOx -crypt drm.xml audio-only.mp4 -out audio-only-enc.mp4`

This is drm.xml:

```
    <GPACDRM type="CENC AES-CTR">
     <DRMInfo type="pssh" version="0">
     <BS ID128="9A04F07998404286AB92E65BE0885F95"/>
     <BS data="application/data;base64:ACE125"/>
     <BS sourceFile="cenc_blob.bin"/>
      </DRMInfo> <DRMInfo type="pssh" version="1" cypherOffset="9" cypherKey="0x6770616363656E6364726D746F6F6C31" cypherIV="0x00000000000000000000000000000001">
      <BS ID128="6770616363656E6364726D746F6F6C31"/>
      <BS value="2" bits="32"/>
      <BS ID128="0x279926496a7f5d25da69f2b3b2799a7f"/>
      <BS ID128="0x676cb88f302d10227992649885984045"/>
      <BS bits="8" string="CID=Toto"/>
      <BS ID128="0xccc0f2b3b279926496a7f5d25da692f6"/>
      <BS ID128="0xccc0f2b3b279926496a7f5d25da692d6"/>
       </DRMInfo>
    <CrypTrack trackID="2" IsEncrypted="1" IV_size="16" first_IV="0x0a610676cb88f302d10ac8bc66e039ed" saiSavedBox="senc">
       <key KID="0x279926496a7f5d25da69f2b3b2799a7f" value="0xccc0f2b3b279926496a7f5d25da692f6"/>
      </CrypTrack>
    </GPACDRM>

Well, now i would to decrypt that file with mpeg-dash. 
In first, i've created .mpd and segmentated that mp4 file.

.Mpd file looks like following:

    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <!-- MPD file Generated with GPAC version 0.6.2-DEV-rev1147-g47f9373-master  at 2016-12-03T10:37:20.403Z-->
    <MPD xmlns="urn:mpeg:dash:schema:mpd:2011" minBufferTime="PT1.500S" type="static" mediaPresentationDuration="PT0H4M30.118S" maxSegmentDuration="PT0H0M3.994S" profiles="urn:mpeg:dash:profile:full:2011" xmlns:cenc="urn:mpeg:cenc:2013">
     <ProgramInformation moreInformationURL="http://gpac.io">
     <Title>audio-enc.mpd generated by GPAC</Title>
     </ProgramInformation>

     <Period duration="PT0H4M30.118S">
     <AdaptationSet segmentAlignment="true" lang="und">
     <ContentProtection schemeIdUri="urn:mpeg:dash:mp4protection:2011" value="cenc" cenc:default_KID="27992649-6a7f-5d25-da69-f2b3b2799a7f"/>
     <Representation id="1" mimeType="audio/mp4" codecs="mp4a.40.2" audioSamplingRate="44100" startWithSAP="1" bandwidth="103460">
     <AudioChannelConfiguration schemeIdUri="urn:mpeg:dash:23003:3:audio_channel_configuration:2011" value="2"/>
     <SegmentList timescale="44100" duration="176400">
     <Initialization sourceURL="segment_audioinit.mp4"/>
     <SegmentURL media="segment_audio1.m4s"/>
     <SegmentURL media="segment_audio2.m4s"/>

      ....

     <SegmentURL media="segment_audio67.m4s"/>
     <SegmentURL media="segment_audio68.m4s"/>
    </SegmentList>
   </Representation>
  </AdaptationSet>
 </Period>
</MPD>
```

Now, this is html of my page:

```
 <!doctype html>
    <html>
     <head>
        <title>Dash.js Rocks</title>
        <style>
            video {
                width: 640px;
                height: 360px;
            }
        </style>
     </head>
     <body>
        <div>
            <video id="videoPlayer" controls></video>
        </div>
        <script src="http://cdn.dashjs.org/latest/dash.all.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>

        <script>
            (function(){
                var url = "http://localhost:8080/prova-enc/audio-enc.mpd";
                              var player = dashjs.MediaPlayer().create();
                player.initialize(document.querySelector("#videoPlayer"), url, true);
            })();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And this is "main.js":

```
'use strict';

    var KEY = new Uint8Array([
    0x279926496a7f5d25da69f2b3b2799a7f
 ]);

    var config = [{
   initDataTypes: ['mp4'],
   videoCapabilities: [{
   contentType: 'video/mp4; codecs="mp4a.40.2"'
  }]
}];

 var video = document.querySelector('videoPlayer');
 if(video) {
      video.addEventListener('encrypted', handleEncrypted, false);
 }

  navigator.requestMediaKeySystemAccess('org.w3.clearkey', config).then(
   function(keySystemAccess) {
   return keySystemAccess.createMediaKeys();
  }
 ).then(
   function(createdMediaKeys) {
   return video.setMediaKeys(createdMediaKeys);
 }
).catch(
  function(error) {
  console.error('Failed to set up MediaKeys', error);
  }
);

 function handleEncrypted(event) {
  console.log('encrypted event:', event);
 var session = video.mediaKeys.createSession();
 session.addEventListener('message', handleMessage, false);
 session.generateRequest(event.initDataType, event.initData).catch(
  function(error) {
  console.error('Failed to generate a license request', error);
    }
  );
 }
```

When i go to my page, on my server, from Chrome (Versione 55.0.2883.75 (64-bit)) this is the output of console:

```
main.js:29 Failed to set up MediaKeys DOMException: None of the requested configurations were supported.
(anonymous) @ main.js:29
Debug.js:108 [23] EME detected on this user agent! (ProtectionModel_21Jan2015) 
Debug.js:108 [29] Playback Initialized 
Debug.js:108 [49] [dash.js 2.3.0] MediaPlayer has been initialized 
XHRLoader.js:223 XHR finished loading: GET "http://localhost:8080/prova-enc/audio-enc.mpd".
c @ XHRLoader.js:223
d @ XHRLoader.js:256
d @ ManifestLoader.js:83
Q @ StreamController.js:663
Pb @ MediaPlayer.js:1928
Fb @ MediaPlayer.js:1772
Db @ MediaPlayer.js:1736
b @ MediaPlayer.js:169
(anonymous) @ dash1.html:23
(anonymous) @ dash1.html:24
Debug.js:108 [70] Parsing complete: ( xml2json: 10.3ms, objectiron: 4.63ms, total: 0.0150s) 
Debug.js:108 [72] Manifest has been refreshed at Sat Dec 03 2016 16:16:33 GMT+0100 (CET)[1480778193.925]  
Debug.js:108 [82] SegmentTimeline detected using calculated Live Edge Time 
Debug.js:108 [89] MediaSource attached to element.  Waiting on open... 
Debug.js:108 [95] MediaSource is open! 
Debug.js:108 [96] Duration successfully set to: 270.118 
Debug.js:108 [98] Added 0 inline events 
Debug.js:108 [98] No video data. 
Debug.js:108 [99] audio codec: audio/mp4;codecs="mp4a.40.2" 
Debug.js:108 [110] Schedule controller stopping for audio 
Debug.js:108 [115] No text data. 
Debug.js:108 [115] No fragmentedText data. 
Debug.js:108 [116] No embeddedText data. 
Debug.js:108 [116] No muxed data. 
Debug.js:108 [117] Start Event Controller 
Debug.js:108 [120] Schedule controller starting for audio 
Debug.js:108 [122] Native video element event: play 
XHRLoader.js:223 XHR finished loading: GET "http://localhost:8080/prova-enc/segment_audioinit.mp4".
c @ XHRLoader.js:223
d @ XHRLoader.js:256
d @ FragmentLoader.js:96
n @ FragmentModel.js:159
l @ FragmentModel.js:150
o @ ScheduleController.js:260
d @ ScheduleController.js:168
y @ ScheduleController.js:303
(anonymous) @ EventBus.js:87
c @ EventBus.js:87
R @ Stream.js:457
Q @ Stream.js:437
d @ Stream.js:124
b @ StreamController.js:427
Debug.js:108 [128] Init fragment finished loading saving to audio's init cache 
Debug.js:108 [136] DRM: onNeedKey 
Debug.js:108 [136] DRM: initData: /psshy@B«æ[à_
[148] DRM: KeySystem Access Denied! -- Key system access denied!
```

Can someone helps me? I'm desperate.

Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Your key should be an array of bytes; your line `new Uint8Array([0x279926496a7f5d25da69f2b3b2799a7f])` incorrectly creates a single-member array. Instead, you should write it as `new Uint8Array([0x27, 0x99, 0x26, 0x49, 0x6a, 0x7f, 0x5d, 0x25, 0xda, 0x69, 0xf2, 0xb3, 0xb2, 0x79, 0x9a, 0x7f])`. It then still needs to be encoded to base64 format before use in the [JsonWebKey](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7517).

Also, you are never generating a license with the key. If you haven't already, please refer to the source of this [example page](https://github.com/samdutton/simpl/blob/gh-pages/eme/clearkey/js/main.js) for the correct way to set up a video with ClearKey. Integrate its `generateLicense()` function into your code (you will also need its `toBase64()` function to convert your key into the right format). In fact, I would recommend getting that code working on your own machine as-is before writing your own version. Note that it needs to run on a secure context (eg. HTTPS) and, if you want to use their video file, you'll need it to be on the same origin as the app (ie. you will need to host it on your own server).

EDIT: also, the "DOMException: None of the requested configurations were supported." indicates that you may have written your `config` incorrectly (or specified features that your environment does not support). Unfortunately, I can't help with this because the specification is quite undefined here and I'm struggling with it myself. Again, I suggest getting that minimum working example to run first.